# MySQL MERGE Implementation

Tags: mysql

There are two tables in my MySQL database which have a many-to-many relationship. There is a third table which handles it, with the foreign keys of the first two.

I need to update the relationship. I may have to add a row with a new relation and delete a row that represents a relation that does not exist any more. To take track of the changes, I created a new table that contains all the relations that are valid, and does not contain the old ones that are meant to be deleted.

There is a lot of content on this `MERGE` statement for SQL, which would solve my problem:

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-merge-statement-overview-and-examples/
https://codingsight.com/merge-updating-source-and-target-tables-located-on-separate-servers/
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/
https://www.educba.com/mysql-merge/

The problem is that for some unclear reason `MERGE` does not exist in MySQL. It kinda has an alternative, called `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but it is not the same and does not cover what I am aiming here. I don't want to delete all the relations on the table and re-insert the new ones.

I would like to know if there is any other alternative to `MERGE`in MySQL, or any way to "add" it to my database.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you're trying to do here. Could you please upload or show us the example you're having. What the data you have is, and what you want it to look like after the query is ran? Off the top of my head, I would assume that you can do an insert after doing an left join, with some where clauses on it. But without seeing the data, I'm flying blind.

Comment: In MySQL there exists: `INSERT [IGNORE] INTO ..` (insert new, skip existing), `REPLACE INTO ..` (insert new, replace existing), `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (insert new, combine existing with new data like you need). [MySQL: DML Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-data-manipulation-statements.html).

Comment: MySQL has had the feature request to implement `MERGE` since 2005: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9018 but there is no comment on whether they will ever do it. I understand it would be a huge effort, because `MERGE` has a lot of functionality that would have to be implemented and tested. I assume the MySQL team has judged that their efforts have been better spent on other improvements every year since then.